# If elements are touching, split their width in half?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a Javascript/jQuery calendar which includes a month view and a day view. Clicking the days will change the date, which will update the date variables in the day view.

The day view is split up into half hour segments from midnight to 11:00 PM. Clicking on any half hour `<tr>` (the day view is a table) will create an event between that time clicked and an hour in the future, as well as append a `div` on top of the calendar, spanning the range of time and positioned at the correct starting point (each pixel is a minute...)

There is a problem, *however*. If you create an "event" between a certain time span where there is already one in place, they overlap. This is the default behavior, obviously, but what I would like to happen is that if an event is created between a range of dates that is already occupied by an event, they align side by side so that they're not overlapping.

This resembles the behavior seen in the iCal app for mac:
[image]

Now my first thought to achieve such a goal was to use collision detection, but all the jQuery plugins for this are bloated or require the elements to be draggable.

Then I thought there might be a way in CSS to do this, where if two elements are overlapping, they split the width evenly.

Then I thought that's ridiculously far fetched, so I'm wondering how I can achieve this as easily as possible.

I'll post the full code in a jsFiddle, but for the most important function would be `insertEvent` which looks like this:

```
    function insertEvent(start, end){

        var end_minutes = new Date(end).getMinutes();
        var end_border = new Date(new Date(end).setMinutes(end_minutes + 2));

        //$(".day_date").html(start + "<br />" + end);
        var diff = Math.abs(end_border - new Date(start));
        var minutes = Math.floor((diff/1000)/60);

        var start_element = $("td").find("[data-date='" + start + "']");
        var offset = start_element.offset().top - $(".second").offset().top;

        var this_element = $("<div class='event' style='height:" + minutes + "px;margin-top:" + offset + "px;'></div>");

        $(".right").prepend(this_element);

    }
```

This takes two parameters in the javascript `new Date()` format, one for the start date and one for the end date.

The fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/charlescarver/HwdwL/

Comment: I'm confused .. how do you see the problem you're trying to fix?  Like how do you add events to a time?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. `Like how do you add events to a time?` The events functionality isn't done yet, like name of event, duration, but I'm trying to lay the groundwork

Comment: @charlie, Explosion Pills is wondering how you structure the data and persist it in memory. If you attach an event to a specific point in time. How is that structured?

Comment: The data will be sent to a database and retrieved upon load. What do you mean how is that structured? All the code is above... when you create an event, it sets it up for a range of time and inserts a visual representation into the day planner, which is what I'm having trouble with here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the the problems I see with your approach is that there isn't a structure to the storage of the data. I've built a calendar in Javascript before and it's not easy work. First, make sure you have some kind of abstraction for the calendar event. Something like:

```
function CalendarEvent(startDateTime, endDateTime) {
  this.startDateTime = startDateTime;
  this.endDateTime = endDateTime;
}

CalendarEvent.prototype.start = function() {
  return this.startDateTime.getTime();
};

CalendarEvent.prototype.end = function() {
  return this.endDateTime.getTime();
};

CalendarEvent.new = function(startDateTime, endDateTime) {
  // This is a little factory method. It prevents calendar events 
  // from having end times that fall before the start time.
  // USE THIS TO INSTANTIATE A NEW CALENDAR EVENT
  if(endDateTime.getTime() < startDateTime.getTime()) {
    throw new Error("End time falls before start time");
  }
  return new CalendarEvent(startDateTime, endDateTime);
};

CalendarEvent.compare = function(eventOne, eventTwo) {
  // this is a class method to compare two events
  // If used with sort it will sort by startDateTime
  return eventOne.start() - eventTwo.start();
};

// ... add any other methods you need
```

Next you're going to want to sort the calendar events. I would sort by start time. Then once it is sorted you can actually re-render everything when changes are made. As long as you sort correctly, determining if a calendar event collides is as simple as this:

```
CalendarEvent.prototype.intersects = function(otherEvent) {
  // If the other event starts after this one ends 
  // then they don't intersect
  if(otherEvent.start() > this.end()) {
    return false;
  }
  // If the other event ends before this one starts
  // then they don't intersect
  if(otherEvent.end() < this.start()) {
    return false;
  }
  // Everything else is true
  return true;
};
```

Because the data is sorted you know that if two or more calendar events intersect they will have to share the space. Granted, you must think about a few things when you divide the space. Do you want a naive implementation where you just share the space equally from left to right (left having the earliest start time). If so your visual representation could look like this if it had 4 events that shared a space (each block is an event):

[image: naive rendering]

However if your events have strange shapes they might cause your calendar to look strange. Consider the following:

[image: possible scenario]

In this instance event 2 takes up a lot of vertical space and all the space underneath event 1 is unused. Maybe for a better UX you don't want that kind of thing to happen. If so you should design your rendering algorithm accordingly. Just remember that it is probably easiest to re-render on every change that you encounter, but it's all about how you store the data. If you do not store the data in some kind of structure that is easily traversed then you won't be able to do this kind of thing.

But to complete the answer to your question, here is a fairly naive example. I haven't tested it so this is a pretty big assumption of it working. It is not entirely complete you will have to edit the rendering for yourself. This is merely to give you an idea of how to get it to work. It could definitely look prettier:

```
function renderCalendarEvents(calendarEvents) {
  // Sort the calendar events (assuming calendarEvents is an array)
  var sortedEvents = calendarEvents.sort(CalendarEvent.compare);
  var index = 0;
  // renderEvents is an anonymous function that will be called every time 
  // you need to render an event
  // it returns it's columnDivisor.
  var renderEvent = function(position) {
    var currentEvent = sortedEvents[index];
    var nextEvent = sortedEvents[index + 1];
    // The default column divisor is determined by
    // the current x-position + 1
    var columnDivisor = position + 1;
    // Increment before any recursion
    index += 1;
    // Check if nextEvent even exists
    if(nextEvent) {
      // If the nextEvent intersects with the current event
      // then recurse
      if(currentEvent.intersects(nextEvent)) {
        // We need to tell the next event that it starts at the
        // column position that is immediately +1 to the current event
        columnDivisor = renderEvent(position + 1);
      }
    }
    // placeEvent() is some function you can call to actually place 
    // the calendar event element on the page
    // The position is the x-position of the current event
    // The columnDivisor is a count of the amount of events sharing this column
    placeEvent(currentEvent, position, columnDivisor);
    return columnDivisor;
  };
  while(true) {
    // render events until we're done
    renderEvent(0);
    if(index >= sortedEvents.length) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially the idea with this particular algorithm is that if the nextEvent on the list exists and that event intersects with the currentEvent then we need to split the width of the currentEvent. It keeps on recursing until it finds no more intersections then it makes it's way back up the chain of recursive calls. I skipped the actual DOM manipulation logic because really the hard part is determining how much you need to split the actual column in order to get these events to fit. So hopefully this all makes a little bit of sense.

EDIT:

To be much more clear, in order to add this to your existing code I would replace your `insertEvent` function with something like this. I don't write all of the logic for you so you'll have to do some of your own writing. But that's half the fun :-).

```
function insertEvent(start, end) {
  var newEvent = Calendar.new(start, end);
  // you'll have to store the array somewhere.
  // i'm just assuming some kind of global right now
  eventsArray.push(newEvent);
  // You'll want to destroy any event elements
  destroyCurrentEventElements();
  // Now run the rendering function
  renderCalendarEvents(eventsArray);
}
```

Comment: Why couldn't I just check to see if new events clash with the event that is added, and if it is, arrange it accordingly?

Comment: How exactly do you determine if they clash? Without sorting the events you have no insight into when events collide. Collision detection is far more complex to setup.

Comment: What if I was to store each event's time with localStorage, then check to see if the new event's start or end time fell between the times of the localStorage values, and if it did, find the element that it'd be overlapping with, set it's width to 50%, then set the current event's width to 50%?

Comment: @Charlie, localStorage is a key-value storage. That means you don't have any way to do a range query meaning you have no way of checking if the event's time fell between the times of any other events without iterating through every item in the database. Regardless of what you do you won't find an O(1) solution it'll always be at least O(n).

Comment: @Charlie, also consider this as well. If you add an item that clashes with two other items, how will you decide how much width to give each item if you try to handle each event separately from the others.

Comment: If each event has the data attribute set with it's start and end, I could match all elements that have those attributes. How are you suggesting I store the data then?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23397/discussion-between-ravenac95-and-charlie)